# How to modify existing Domain and update new attribute into Bootstrap?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Well, I'll simplify the problem so you can understand it better.
I have a software in production with a domain named `Person` with some attributes.
I've added a new attribute named `Contact` into `Person` domain and `Contact` need to be updated when I start my application getting some information from `Person.AnotherContactObject`.

So in my `Bootstrap.groovy` I'm trying to do this:

```
List<Person> persons = Person.findAll()
for(Person person : persons){
   person.contact = new Contact()
   person.save(flush:true)
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
context.GrailsContextLoader Error initializing the application: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.test.Contact; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.test.Contact
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.test.Contact; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.test.Contact
    at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:154)
    at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:308)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:301)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.test.Contact
    ... 8 more
```

Well, I also tried to solve this way:

Create new `Contact` object, save it, and set it in `person.contact` and save `person` object, but still with the same error.

Comment: Try removing flush:true. If that fails you could wrap above block with Person.withTransaction {...}

Comment: Probably there is validation error in your `Contact` class. Try printing `person.contact.validate(); println person.contact.errors`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `Contact` is also a domain class. You need to save `Contact` before you can save `Person`.

```
List<Person> persons = Person.findAll().each { person ->
   person.contact = new Contact().save(flush:true)
   person.save(flush:true)
}
```

Of course, don't forget to set all non-nullable properties in the `Contact` instance before saving it.